# Can we change the value of an object defined with const through pointers?

Tags: c, constants, undefined-behavior

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const int a = 12;
    int *p;
    p = &a;
    *p = 70;
}
```

Will it work?

Comment: Many duplicates, e.g. [constants and pointers in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945640/constants-and-pointers-in-c)

Comment: Maybe you can try to use a pointer of pointer to acces the const int a.

    `*(int*) p = 70;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I change a local const variable through pointer casts but not a global one in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945640/why-can-i-change-a-local-const-variable-through-pointer-casts-but-not-a-global-o)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's "undefined behavior," meaning that based on the standard you can't predict what will happen when you try this. It may do different things depending on the particular machine, compiler, and state of the program.

In this case, what will most often happen is that the answer will be "yes." A variable, const or not, is just a location in memory, and you can break the rules of constness and simply overwrite it. (Of course this will cause a severe bug if some other part of the program is depending on its const data being constant!)

However in some cases -- most typically for `const static` data -- the compiler may put such variables in a read-only region of memory. MSVC, for example, usually puts const static ints in .text segment of the executable, which means that the operating system will throw a protection fault if you try to write to it, and the program will crash.

In some other combination of compiler and machine, something entirely different may happen. The one thing you *can* predict for sure is that this pattern will annoy whoever has to read your code.

Comment: I tried similar codein ideone and it crashed. Is there reliable method to actually change the variable?

Comment: Since the value is assumed constant, the compiler is also free to optimize memory accesses by using the value as an immediate value in an instruction rather than using an extra load instruction to fetch it from memory. So you can get a lot of strange states here: variable was eliminated entirely by the optimizer, uses in some places reference the variable, but in other places use an immediate (which your hack didn't change), etc. (I'm not sure how likely it is that the const is only *partially* changed to an immediate, but I'm pretty sure immediate replacement is possible).

Answer (score 15):

It's undefined behaviour.  Proof:

```
/* program.c */

int main()
{
        const int a = 12;
        int* p;
        p = &a;
        *p = 70;
        printf("%d\n", a);
        return 0;
}


gcc program.c
```

and run it.  Output will be 70 (gcc 4.3)

Then compile it like this:

```
gcc -O2 program.c
```

and run it.  The output will be 12.  When it does optimisation, the compiler presumably loads 12 into a register and doesn't bother to load it again when it needs to access a for the printf because it "knows" that a can't change.

Comment: Funny, when I run this program, the output is 42.

Comment: @abelenky: yes but did you stop to think about what the question is?  Maybe you should build a computer to find out.

Comment: The fact that gcc behaves oddly given a piece of code would only mean the code invokes Undefined Behavior if gcc upheld the Standard in every case.  In practice, however, gcc is incapable of efficiently handling certain semantics required of a conforming compiler, and instead of handling them in a way that's conforming but inefficient, or fixing their execution model to handle them in efficient and conforming, manner, gcc ops instead to handle them in a way that's "efficient" but broken and non-conforming.

Comment: @supercat In this case, gcc is behaving according to the standard. Using a pointer to write to a `const` object is UB. The reason it is UB is because, in practice, it's hard to enforce logically correct behaviour without OS level memory protection.

Comment: @JeremyP: In this *particular* case, the code happens to invoke UB, and I didn't mean to imply otherwise.  I was questioning the general assumption that a piece of code which fails on gcc is invoking UB rather than merely exposing a place where gcc doesn't follow the Standard.

Comment: Proof of UB would be quoting the standard,  not examining code output

Comment: Cannot assign const int * to int *. Typecast it to (int *).

Answer (score 11):

Modifying a `const` qualified object through a pointer invokes undefined behaviour, and such is the result. It may be something you'd expect from a particular implementation, e.g. the previous value unchanged, if it has been placed in `.text`, etc.

Comment: Another possible result is "some expressions behave as if `a` is still 12, while others behave as if `a` is now 70", which may or may not be "something you'd expect".

Answer (score 6):

It does indeed work with gcc. It didn't like it though:

> test.c:6: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type

But the value did change when executed. I won't point out the obvious no-no...

Answer (score 4):

yes, you can make it done by using such code. but the code do not apply when when `a` is global (a gcc-compiled program gave me `segmentation fault`.)

generally speaking, in beloved C, you can almost always find someway to hack things that are not supposed to be changed or exposed. const here being a example.

But thinking about the poor guy(maybe myself after 6 months) maintains our code, I often choose not do so.

Answer (score 1):

Here the type of pointer `p` is `int*`, which is being assigned the value of type `const int*` (`&a` => address of a `const int` variable).

Implicit cast eliminates the constness, though gcc throws a warning (please note this largely depends on the implementation).

Since the pointer is not declared as a `const`, value can be changed using such pointer.

if the pointer would be declared as `const int* p = &a`, you won't be able to do `*p = 70`.

Comment: But you could update the variable A can’t you? So you can’t change what a const pointer points at, but you can change the object tgat it points at. Yes? Eg. Int a = 5; Const *p = &a; *p = 7;

Answer (score 1):

This code contains a *constraint violation*:

```
const int a = 12;
int *p;
p = &a;
```

The constraint violated is C11 6.5.16.1/1 "Simple assignment"; if both operands are pointers then the type pointed to by the left must have all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right. (And the types, sans qualifiers, must be compatible).

So the constraint is violated because `&a` has type `const int *`, which has `const` as a qualifier; but that qualifier does not appear in the type of `p` which is `int *`.

The compiler must emit a diagnostic and might not generate an executable. The behaviour of any executable would be completely undefined, since the program does not comply with the rules of the language.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the value of a constant variable by using a pointer pointing to it. This type of pointer is called as `Pointer to a constant`.

There is also another concept called `Constant Pointer`. It means that once a pointer points to a memory location you cannot make it point to the another location.

Answer (score 0):

Bad, BAD idea.

Also, the behavior is platform- and implementation-specific. If you're running on a platform where the constant is stored in non-writable memory, this obviously won't work.

And, why on earth would you want to? Either update the constant in your source, or make it a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with changing the value of `const` variable is that the compiler will not expect that to happen. Consider this code:

```
const int a = 12;
int * p = &a;
*p = 70;
printf("%d\n", a);
```

Why would the compiler read `a` in the last statement? The compiler knows that `a` is `12` and since it is `const`, it will never change. So the optimizer may transform the code above into this:

```
const int a = 12;
int * p = &a;
*p = 70;
printf("%d\n", 12);
```

This can lead to strange issues. E.g. the code might work as desired in debug builds without optimization but it will fail in release builds with optimization.

Actually a good optimizer might transform the **entire** code to this:

```
printf("%d\n", 12);
```

As all other code before has no effect in the eye of the compiler. Leaving out code that has no effect will also have no effect on the overall program.

On the other hand, a decent compiler will recognize, that your code is faulty and warn you, since

```
int * p = &a;
```

is actually wrong. Correct would be:

```
const int * p = &a;
```

as `p` is not a pointer to `int`, it is a pointer to `const int` and when declared like that, the next line will cause a hard compile error.

To get rid of the warning, you have to cast:

```
int * p = (int *)&a;
```

And an even better compiler will recognize that this cast breaks the `const` promise and instruct the optimizer to not treat `a` as `const`.

As you can see, the quality, capabilities and settings of the compilerwill decide in the end what behavior you can expect. This implies that the same code may show different behavior on different platforms or when using different compilers on the same platform.

If the C standard had defined a behavior for that case, all compilers would have to implement it and no matter what the standard had defined, it would have been hard to implement, putting a huge burden on everyone who wants to write a compiler. Even if the standard had just said "This is forbidden", all compilers would have to perform complex data flow analysis to enforce this rule. So the standard just doesn't define it. It defines that `const` values cannot be changed and if you find a way to change them anyway, there is no behavior you can rely on.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can change the value of a constant variable.
Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const  int x=10;

    int *p;
    p=(int*)&x;
    *p=12;
    printf("%d",x);
}
```