# Can constant objects with static storage duration and equal, constant initializers be coalesced?

Tags: c, c99, language-lawyer, sentinel

Consider two objects with static storage duration and equal, constant initializers:

```c
static const int a = 50;
static const int b = 50;
```

Is it valid for a compiler to combine these such that `&a == &b`?

(For context, I was thinking of using static constant objects to get unique addresses to use as sentinel pointer values. If it is legal for a compiler to combine such objects and I use the same constant value for two such objects, then the addresses could be equal and I cannot use them as sentinel values.)

Comment: Hmm... Strings are allowed to be pooled. So if I had to guess, this might actually be allowed.

Comment: Essentially, Your question is are objects with static storage duration guaranteed to have unique addresses. The answer is **No**, the standard does not mandate any such guarantee.

Comment: Related (though different, due to lack of `static`): [Are `const` variables required to be distinct in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6236762)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointers must compare not-equal. See C99 6.5.9 paragraph 6:

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space.

Answer (score 1):

No, the standard forbids that.  Distinct objects must have distinct addresses.   In `const char a[]="abc", b[]="abc";`, `a` and `b` are allocated at different addresses.  This is also true if they're pointers: in `const char *a="abc", *b="abc",`a`and`b` are also allocated at different addresses; the string constant they point to can be a single constant array, just as if it was a named object.

Comment: Can you point to the section of the standard that states that?

Comment: Strictly speaking the only thing that is guaranteed is the result of the equality test; that test is also the only way a program can observe whether two objects are the same or not. This is no accident and stems from the way the C notion of an object is defined.

Comment: @icktoofay 6.5.9.8p6, which I didn't know myself but found by googling "must distinct objects have distinct addresses C", the top hit is http://stackoverflow.com/a/6237094/1290731

Comment: Thank you. That answer you linked to is very interesting.