# integer pointer to constant integer

Tags: c++

I'd like to know what is happening internally and its relation to values displayed. 
The code is:

```
# include <iostream>

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    const int a = 10;

    int* p = &a;  //When compiling it generates warning "initialization from int* to 
              //const int* discard const -- but no error is generated

    cout << &a <<"\t" << p <<endl; //output: 0x246ff08 0x246ff08 (same values)
    cout << a << "\t" << *p << endl; //output: 10 10

    //Now..
    *p = 11;
    cout << &a <<"\t" << p <<endl; //output: 0x246ff08 0x246ff08 (essentially, 
                               //same values and same as above, but..)
    cout << a << "\t" << *p << endl; //output: 10 11

    return 0;
}
```

QUESTION: If p = address-of-a, how come a=10, but *p = (goto address of a and read value in the memory location) = 11?

Comment: You're lying to the compiler. Now you complain that the compiler is lying to you. You reap what you sow.

Comment: @user Since you cannot accept Kerrek's comment, you should accept ouah's answer

Comment: "but no error is generated" -- It's sometimes useful to remember that the implementation is not required to issue an _error_ for an ill-formed program; it is merely required to issue a _diagnostic_ (unless otherwise specified), which it in this case does. It is allowed, however, to compile and run ill-formed programs. This is desirable, for example, if you want to use an old C library routine that takes a pointer to non-`const` `char` but doesn't actually modify the pointee. If you want the compiler to enforce tighter restrictions, consider using at least `-pedantic` and `-Werror`.

Comment: this is embarrassing.. i actually am no longer working on c++, so i left this question. Also, i am not sure if there's something wrong about my installation, older version.. because most answers suggested that this behavior "should" not happen, so I don' really know what was the cause.

Answer (score 8):

```
 cout << a << "\t" << *p << endl; //output: 10 11
```

You lied to the compiler and it got its revenge.

With:

```
const int a = 10;
```

you promised you'll never modify `a` object.

Answer (score 5):

You promised not to modify `a`, and the compiler believed you. So it decided to optimise away the reading of `a`, because it trusted you. You broke your promise.

Having said that, a real C++ compiler won't compile your code because `int* p = &a` is illegal. So perhaps you are lying to us as well. Or perhaps you need to get a real C++ compiler.

Comment: Fun fact: Compilers usually cry themselves to sleep

Comment: ...and wake up to their own screams.

Comment: Please.. i am baffled myself.. and have checked the code multiply.. since its a small code, Can I please request you to try it yourself and check the result.. maybe it is that I'm just working on a funky compiler! by the way.. same results come when using references instead of pointer

Comment: The code should not compile. It is illegal. My compilers won't compile it. Your compiler sucks. Given that it does compile, well, you lied to the compiler about `a` being `const`, and as Kerrek SB says, "you reap what you sow". It is time to get a better compiler. Are you using Turbo C++?

Answer (score 2):

Just like Ouah said compiler has taken its revenge

but I disagree with you that it doesn't give any error

```
const int a = 10;

int* p = &a;
```

You cannot assign constant to a non constant pointer.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought this was only a warning due to the history of how `const` came into C.

Comment: Either I am using a wrong compiler or he is :-p because I am sure this is impossible

Comment: @chux: It's only a warning _in some compilers_ but they're technically breaking the rules on your behalf

Comment: @Mooing Duck - in either case warning or error, can not see why one would ignore such a warning.

Comment: @Mooing Duck - Warning? whats the use of `const` then

Comment: @Hamza To give a hint to the compiler. It's not to protect you from anything, but to allow the compiler to make some better assumptions about your code.

Comment: @JustSid If that was so then I guess we would not need `const_cast`. The code in the question is not valid C++.

Comment: @chux: They made it a warning so that code that compiled on the previous versions of the compiler still compiles in this version of the compiler.

Comment: Can I please request if someone else try the same code and check the result.. maybe I'm just working on a funky compiler! by the way.. same results come when using references instead of pointer.

Comment: Just curious, I recall seeing a similar question and I believe it's undefined behavior. Is it not?

Comment: Agree with David.. `const` was introduced because it has an advantage for programmers over the C preprocessor `#define` because it is understood & used by the compiler itself so it can give error when changed, You are messing with the concepts here I believe, if they could incorporate the warning, they could made that an error when new keyword was added.

Comment: @user3272925 Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I don't know inner details.. am pretty new! I followed instructions from http://www.claremontmckenna.edu/pages/faculty/alee/g++/g++.html

Comment: Ever heard about visual studio?

Comment: @Hamza MSVC is fine. It won't compile this.

Comment: I know thats why I asked. I am 100% sure, that it wont compile on any compiler. Will definitely try on above mentioned compiler and if it does compile, I will sue them ;)

Answer (score 0):

In C, this is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801557/can-we-change-the-value-of-a-constant-through-pointers). In C++, this won't compile. It's been repeated by [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565078/integer-pointer-to-constant-integer#comment32572203_21565150) multiple times but it is worth repeating. Here is the error you should get on a modern compiler:

```
main.cpp:7:10: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an rvalue of type 'const int *'

    int* p = &a;  //When compiling it generates warning "initialization from int* to
```