# Modifying const int variable by int pointer

Tags: c++, c

I read that in [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/const-qualifier-in-c/), that assigning address of const int * to int * is illegal for C++ and throws compiler error.
I tried assigning the const int * to int * by explicit cast and tried changing the value. I couldn't understand the program behavior. I was wondering if it is undefined behavior or there is some reasoning behind it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int const i = 20;
    int * ptr;

    ptr = (int *)&i;

    *ptr = 500;

    printf("%d %d %p %p\n", *ptr, i, ptr, &i);

    return 0;
}
```

The output was

```
500 20 0x7ffe16ea5134 0x7ffe16ea5134
```

Comment: It is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Modifying a `const` object is always UB

Comment: See: [Can we change the value of an object defined with const through pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3801557/1275169).

Comment: Cast away the `const` to defeat the compiler warning, and you are off on your own.

Comment: Also, a const object cannot be modified. so its undefined behavior.

Comment: Casting `const int *` to `int *` like that will compile, but it doesn't mean that it is allowed in this case. Many things that are not allowed will compile. See [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Casting away the constness is perfectly acceptable... but only in a few scenarios (which actually includes some where you want to modify the value!)

Comment: @AndyG specifically, it's allowed when the original object wasn't `const` to begin with. That's why `const_cast` exists.

Comment: As far as the output in this example, it's indeed UB since it makes no sense. If you're wondering what the compiler did to get this specific result, it probably optimized the `i` in the `printf` call to a literal since it knew the value couldn't be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I think it makes sense that since compiler could see that that i is const and hence instead of using reference to variable it used the value directly as immediate in assembly.