# Why does this code works changing constant integer?

Tags: c

```
int const i = 10;
int *j = &i;
*j = 20;
printf("%d",i);
```

If i is constant shouldn't it not be changed even through pointers. If not what is the condition for it to not change?

Comment: Doesn't the compiler warn you about this initialisation `int *j = &i;`? I'd expect it to issue something like this: "*warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type*"

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Not this again:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler should emit a warning for this line: `int *j = &i;`.  You make a non const qualified pointer point to a const qualified object.

When you later attempt to modify `i` via the `j` pointer, the behavior is undefined:

- if `i` is writable, it may be modified, and this is what you observe.
- but if you define `i` at the file scope, the compiler may locate it in a read-only segment and the attempt might fail with a segmentation fault.
- anything else could happen, including a presidential meltdown.

Try compiling and running this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int const i = 10;

int main(void) {
    int *j = &i;
    *j = 10;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like the way you illustrate the potential disaster.

Comment: In the present US, a presidential meltdown does not need to be blamed on bad code.

Comment: @aschepler:  Bad code of conduct maybe? Or bad code in voting machines?

Comment: @aschepler really?  I wasted all my time writing bad code and it did not have the desired effect?

Answer (score 2):

[You can change a `const` variable but the behavior is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3801601/1983495).

Your compiler should warn about the loss of `const` in the following line,

```
int *j = &i;
```

So `const` works exactly like that, it just prevents you from accidentally changing a `const` variable because you would listen to your compiler and fix your code before using it.

You can't however, directly assign to `i`.

But through pointers you can always get rid of `const`. Whether the resulting behavior is defined or not, is something you should know before you do get rid of `const`, which is sometimes fine, however if you MUST do it, it probably means you have a design problem.

Comment: (`int *j = &i;`, the line with the warning, is an initialization and not an assignment.)

Comment: @aschepler True, but it's the same problem in both cases. I think my answer is clearer now about the warning.