# Change Value of const varaible by having a pointer?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-optimization

I know I can use the pointers to change value in a const variable in c. Then what is the use of const variable if its value can be changed by using pointer in c? I am asking why we need those ways not how to do so. So it it cant't be a duplicate of [Can we change the value of an object defined with const through pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801557/can-we-change-the-value-of-an-object-defined-with-const-through-pointers).

Comment: Please quote what you are referring to. It sounds like you are walking on treacherous ground by relying on undefined behaviour...

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03d97c7dc810a2e9

Comment: You don't do it.