# How to make a "real" constant in C?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I recently took a look at how pointers work with constants in C, and I read that pointers on constants could lead to modify them:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
  const int x = 1;

  int *y;
  y = &x;

  *y += 1;

  printf("x = %d\n", x); // Prints: 2
  printf("y = %d\n", *y); // Prints: 2

  return 0;
}
```

Here, I define a constant called `x` and make a pointer from it so I can modify its value. This means `x` is not *really* constant. Is there a way to make it *really* constant?

**EDIT :** This question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801557/can-we-change-the-value-of-an-object-defined-with-const-through-pointers) as I am asking here how we can make a *real constant*, not how to change a constant through a pointer.

Comment: `y = &x;` (without explicit `(int *)`) should be a compile-time error, you should adjust your compiler flags (e.g. `-pedantic-errors` if you use GCC or Clang).

Comment: Check this link, detailing a similiar issue : 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/const-qualifier-in-c/

Comment: But after you add the cast (`y = (int*)&x;`) there is nothing you can do. Often constants end up in write-protected memory and cause a segfault if modified, but sometimes not. It aint hard to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: The C standard alone does not provide a way to enforce the `const` property. Operating systems often do. In POSIX, you can allocate one or more pages of memory and use `mprotect` to mark them read-only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, `const` does not define constants; it defines read-only variables.

The line

```
y = &x;
```

is a type error; your compiler should have complained about that ("assignment discards qualifiers" or something similar).

`*y += 1` attempts to modify a read-only object. Not only is this not guaranteed to work, it has undefined behavior (i.e. anything can happen).

In order to make a real constant, you need to use `enum`:

```
enum { x = 1 };
```

Now `&x` is an error because constants do not live in memory and don't have an address.

Unfortunately this technique only works for integers.

A commonly seen alternative is macros:

```
#define X 1
```

This is not a constant at the language level; instead the preprocessor simply replaces any occurrence of `X` by `1` during compilation.

Comment: So, there is no way to define any object as a "real" constant?
And, for the error you mentioned, my compiler (gcc on Ubuntu) only shows a warning.

Comment: @ClementNerma As far as the C standard is concerned, there are only "diagnostics". Whether something is a warning or an error is at the discretion of the compiler. A good first rule of thumb for C is to treat any warning as an error (or tell the compiler to do so: `-Werror`). You also want to enable `-Wall -pedantic -Wextra`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explanation :)