# Subsetting char array without copying it in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a long array of char (coming from a raster file via GDAL), all composed of 0 and 1. To compact the data, I want to convert it to an array of bits (thus dividing the size by 8), 4 bytes at a time, writing the result to a different file. This is what I have come up with by now:

```
uint32_t bytes2bits(char b[33]) {
    b[32] = 0;
    return strtoul(b,0,2);
}

const char data[36] = "00000000000000000000000010000000101"; // 101 is to be ignored
char word[33];
strncpy(word,data,32);
uint32_t byte = bytes2bits(word);
printf("Data: %d\n",byte); // 128
```

The code is working, and the result is going to be written in a separate file. What I'd like to know is: can I do that without copying the characters to a new array?

EDIT: I'm using a const variable here just to make a minimal, reproducible example. In my program it's a char *, which is continually changing value inside a loop.

Comment: Caution: `b[32]` is out of bounds when you pass in `word`.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you. I guess changing char word[32]; to char word[33]; solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, as long as you can modify the source string (in your example code you can't because it is a constant, but I assume in reality you have the string in writable memory):

```
uint32_t bytes2bits(const char* b) {
    return strtoul(b,0,2);
}

void compress (char* data) { 
    // You would need to make sure that the `data` argument always has 
    // at least 33 characters in length (the null terminator at the end 
    // of the original string counts)
    char temp = data[32];
    data[32] = 0;
    uint32_t byte = bytes2bits(data);
    data[32] = temp;
    printf("Data: %d\n",byte); // 128
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But you mean 32 instead of 33, or else the result will be 256 instead of 128.

Answer (score 1):

In this example by using char* as a buffer to store that long data there is not necessary to copy all parts into a temporary buffer to convert it to a long.
Just use a variable to step through the buffer by each 32 byte length period, but after the 32th byte there needs the 0 termination byte.

So your code would look like:

```
uint32_t bytes2bits(const char* b) {
    return strtoul(b,0,2);
}

void compress (char* data) { 
    int dataLen = strlen(data);
    int periodLen = 32;
    char* periodStr;
    char tmp;
    int periodPos = periodLen+1;
    uint32_t byte;

    periodStr = data[0];
    while(periodPos < dataLen)
    {
    tmp = data[periodPos];
    data[periodPos] = 0;

    byte = bytes2bits(periodStr);
    printf("Data: %d\n",byte); // 128

    data[periodPos] = tmp;
    periodStr = data[periodPos];
    periodPos += periodLen;
    }
    if(periodPos - periodLen <= dataLen)
    {
        byte = bytes2bits(periodStr);
        printf("Data: %d\n",byte); // 128
    }
}
```

Please than be careful to the last period, which could be smaller than 32 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

> `const char data[36]`

You are in violation of your contract with the compiler if you declare something as `const` and then modify it.

Generally speaking, the compiler won't let you modify it...so to even *try* to do so with a const declaration you'd have to cast it *(but don't)*

```
char *sneaky_ptr = (char*)data;
sneaky_ptr[0] = 'U'; /* the U is for "undefined behavior" */
```

See: [Can we change the value of an object defined with const through pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801557/can-we-change-the-value-of-an-object-defined-with-const-through-pointers)

So if you wanted to do this, you'd have to be sure the data was legitimately non-const.

Comment: I only declared it as const to make a minimal, reproducible example. In my program it isn't const.

Comment: @Rodrigo I misread the docs for strtoul.  If you want to in-place convert an arbitrarily long buffer of 1s and 0s to bytes, you can do so...but you wouldn't want to use strtoul to do that.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I explained it better in the text now. It's no in-place conversion. The converted values are going to a different file.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this in modern C++ is by using `std::string` to hold your string and [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) to process parts of that string without copying it.

You can using `string_view` with that char array you have though. It's common to use it to modernize the classical null-terminated string `const char*`.

Comment: Please take a look at lxop's answer. I think it's more efficient, isn't it?

Comment: @Rodrigo No, it's the same. Except that it uses old methods.

Comment: The same program done in C++ is usually bigger than in C. That's why I thought it could be different. I don't know the internal implementation of std::string, much less string_view. So I'd have to take your word for it.