# Why is strtoul returning 0 from a "1" string?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, strtoul

I'm trying to compact a raster file in a way that is easy to read without GDAL library (my web server cannot install GDAL). Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53571634/1086511), I'm doing the following to convert a raster's bytes (only 0 and 1 values) to bits:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        return 1;
    }
    GDALDataset *poDataset;
    GDALAllRegister();
    poDataset = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpen(argv[1],GA_ReadOnly);
    if (poDataset == NULL) {
        return 2;
    }
    int tx=poDataset->GetRasterXSize(), ty=poDataset->GetRasterYSize();
    GDALRasterBand *poBand;
    int nBlockXSize,nBlockYSize;
    poBand = poDataset->GetRasterBand(1);
    printf("Type: %s\n",GDALGetDataTypeName(poBand->GetRasterDataType()));
    // Type: Byte
    poBand->GetBlockSize(&nBlockXSize,&nBlockYSize);
    int i, nX = tx/nBlockXSize, nY = ty/nBlockYSize;
    char *data = (char*)CPLMalloc(nBlockXSize*nBlockYSize + 1);
    uint32_t out[nBlockXSize*nBlockYSize/32];
    char temp;
    CPLErr erro;
    FILE* pFile;
    pFile = fopen(argv[2],"wb");
    for (y=0; y<nY; y++) {
        for (x=0; x<nX; x++) {
            erro = poBand->ReadBlock(x,y,data);
            if (erro > 0) {
                return 3;
            }
            for (i=0; i<nBlockXSize*nBlockYSize; i+=32) {
                temp = data[i+32];
                data[i+32] = 0;
                out[i/32] = strtoul(&data[i],0,2);
                if (data[i] != 0) {
                    printf("%u/%u ",data[i],out[i/32]);
                }
                data[i+32] = temp;
            }
            ch = getchar(); // for debugging
        }
        fwrite(out,4,nBlockXSize*nBlockYSize/32,pFile);
    }
    fclose(pFile);
    CPLFree(data);
    return 0;
}
```

After the first set of bytes is read (`for (i=0; i<nBlockXSize*nBlockYSize; i+=32)`), I can see that `printf("%u/%u ",data[i],out[i/32]);` is printing some "1/0", meaning that, where my raster has a 1 value, this is being passed to strtoul, which is returning 0. Obviously I'm messing with something (pointers, probably), but can't find where. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `%d` is the wrong format specifier for `out[i/32]`, this causes undefined behaviour

Comment: `strtoul` converts a sequence of characters to a number, so the first character being `1` doesn't really tell you much, e.g. maybe the string was `100000000000000000000`.   In that case it should really return `ULONG_MAX` (since the input is a correct binary number but it is out of range) and not `0`; the return value of `0` is supposed to indicate that no digits were found, or the value was actually `0`.

Comment: You could try changing your debug print to show more characters , e.g.  
`printf("%.20s", &data[i])`  (assuming that it all contains printable characters), or inspect that in a debugger

Comment: @M.M Changed it to `printf("%u/%u ",data[i],out[i/32]);` but still getting "1/0". Using `printf("%s/%u ",&data[i],out[i/32]);` produces "/0 /0 /0 /0..." (with a different number of non-printable characters before "/0" each time).

Comment: OK, that makes more sense... `data[i]` is `1` (not `'1'`) so there are no matching characters for `strtoul` and therefore `0` returned.  Do you understand the difference between `char x = 1;` and `char x = '1';` ?

Comment: @M.M Ah, of course! Thank you! I'm using the wrong function...

Comment: You allso have an undefined behaviour. Unless `CPLMalloc` gives you one more byte than you ask for, then `data[i+32]` will reach outside the memory allocated to data

Comment: @HAL9000 You are right! This silent bug hasn't bitten yet, but one day it would. I guess `CPLMalloc(nBlockXSize*nBlockYSize+1)` solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtoul` is for converting printable character data to an integer. The string should contain character codes for digits, e.g. `'0'`, `'1'` etc.

Apparently in your case the source data is actually the integer value `1` and so `strtoul` finds there are no characters of the expected form and returns `0` .