# Same C code, different output on Mac & Linux

Tags: c, linux, macos, gcc, undefined-behavior

I was messing with pointers and `const`, while running below code:

```
int main()
{
    const int test = 10;
    int *ptr = &test;
    printf("%d\n", test);
    *ptr = 1;
    printf("%d\n", test);
}
```

on Mac, results were:

```
10
10
```

and on the linux machine:

```
10
1
```

Why change of value didn't worked at Mac?
Both machines compiled code with gcc.

Comment: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/11082165). GCC will tell you what the problem is

Comment: What does `const` mean?

Comment: Re “Why change of value didn't worked at Mac? Both machines compiled code with gcc”: Many years ago, Apple changed its default compiler to Clang and provided a symbolic link from `gcc` to `clang` so that existing scripts would not break. If you have not installed GCC on your system, separately from Apple’s build tools, you are using Clang, not GCC.

Comment: @Brian61354270 - Both, `clang` and `gcc` generate the very same warning, yet still, behave differently. I think that's what worries OP most. Why two different compilers give different behaviour for the very same code. @lukasz - look for something called: `undefined behaviour`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we change the value of an object defined with const through pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801557/can-we-change-the-value-of-an-object-defined-with-const-through-pointers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run your tests on Godbolt's compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/5xfEqj9x1

As can be seen on the output panes, the behavior is consistent with your observations, here are some explanations:

- the code has undefined behavior: you define `test` as a `const int` local variable but you explicitly bypass this by storing its address to an `int *` pointer and set the value via `*ptr = 1`.  Both compilers issue a warning about this dubious assignment, which you purposely ignored. The code `*ptr = 1` has undefined behavior because you are modifying a `const` variable. If `test` had been defined at the global scope (or with a `static` qualifier) this assignment might have triggered a segmentation fault.  In this case, the indirect modification of the variable, if performed at all has no effect because the compiler may assume that the `test` variable does not change.
- **gcc** on macOS is by default an alias for **clang**, which generates different code from **gcc** on linux.  Even without optimisations, **clang** assumes that the `const` variable has not been modified between the 2 `printf` statements and passes `10` as the argument value (via the `esi` register) in both calls.  **gcc** does this with **-O2** or higher optimisation level, but reads the variable value at **-O0**, producing `1` for the second `printf` call on linux.

Executing code with undefined behavior implies anything can happen and different output is a common illustration, which is frustrating because the environment does not point to the problem as explicitly as a segmentation fault would.  *anything can happen* is not to be taken literally, it means unpredictable side effects or lack thereof can happen, including nothing visible, a different value being read, a segmentation fault occurring... Expect the unexpected.

To try and minimize such problems, always add all useful warnings at compile time and fix their causes (eg: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`).

Comment: Re “Undefined behavior means anything can happen”: That is not what “undefined behavior” means.

Comment: It goes towards sort of sophistic discussion ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior - question is whether: `In computer programming, undefined behavior (UB) is the result of executing a program whose behavior is prescribed to be unpredictable` means `anything can happen` or not ;)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: OK, this was a figurative *meaning*: [definition #6](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/mean) is *6  (verb) have as a logical consequence “The water shortage means that we have to stop taking long showers”. synonyms: entail, imply*

Comment: It is not sophistic discussion; it has real-world effects on students. Students start not knowing how computers work, and they get ideas such as a bug in their program can damage their computer. They need to be given truthful precise statements to guide them in the correct direction. “Undefined behavior” in the C standard means **only** that the C standard does not impose any requirements. It does not release the program from any constraints outside the C program, such as operating system constraints, issues of compiler design, physics, consumer product law, and more…

Comment: … The programmer who has learned how bugs affect behavior is a better debugger and a better software engineer than a student who has been taught “anything can happen” and throws up their hands at a problem because they do not understand what the actual causes are. Saying “anything can happen” is false as a matter of fact and is bad teaching.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I agree with you, and I hope my answer provides many details and hints for the OP to investigate and understand what is happening and how to try and avoid silly mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

You ignored diagnostic messages from the compiler and built with different tools and/or different switches on Mac and Linux.

The initialization in `int * ptr = &test;` violates the constraints in C 2018 (the 2018 version of the C standard) 6.5.16.1 1 because it assigns<sup>1</sup> an `int *` value to an object of type `const int *`, and these types are incompatible and not covered by the allowed cases. A conforming compiler is required to issue a diagnostic message for that.

A compiler is allowed to accept the code in spite of the constraint violation, but then the behavior is not defined by the C standard. One of your compilers treated `ptr` as pointing to an object that could change and store new values, and it printed the changed value. The other compiler observed your program was using a `const int` that could be assumed not to change, so, during optimization, it used the original value instead of a changed value.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> This is an initialization, and the rules for initialization refer to the rules for assignment.