# initialized vs uninitialized global const variable in c

Tags: c

Pardon me, I am not very good in explaining questions. So I start with example directly

Look at following example

```
const int a=10;
int *ptr;

int main(){
    ptr=&a; 
    *ptr=100;   // program crashes
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

But If I made a slightly change in above code as following

```
const int a; // uninitialized global variable
```

Then the above code works fine.

So my question is why compiler behaves differently for uninitialize and initialize global const variables?

I am using gcc for windows (mingw).

Comment: Already answered here, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945640/constants-and-pointers-in-c

Comment: You should get compiler warning/error from trying to assign `ptr=&a;`.

Comment: @Ani I read that thats about local vs global variable

Comment: @user694733 Yes I get warning but as per programmer's habbit I just ignore it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are modifying a const object, and that is simply [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - so don't do it, and don't ignore compiler warnings.

Now, the actual reason for the different behavior in your particular case is that for `const int a=10;` the value `10` has to be stored somewhere. Since the variable is const, the linker places it in the .rodata or a similar read only section of the executable. When you're trying to write to a read-only location, you'll get a segmentation fault.

For the uninitialized case, `const int a` , the `a` needs to be initialized to zero since it's at file scope (or; `a` is a global variable). The linker then places the variable in the .bss section, together with other data that also is zero initialized at program startup. The .bss section is read/write and you get no segfault when you try to write to it.

All this is not something you can rely on  , this could change with minor modification to the code, if you use another compiler or a newer/older version of your compiler etc.

Comment: ohh got it :) thankuuu

Actually I am preparing for placements so I have to ignore the warnings because this type of questions are generaly asked

Comment: No, you really can write standards-compliant code and code that generates no warnings even when doing things that are platform-specific. Serious professional programmers do not ignore warnings. You shouldn't either.

Answer (score 6):

Global and static variables are initialized implicitly if your code doesn't do it explicitly as mandated by the C standard.

From the doc:

> const is a type qualifier. The other type qualifier is volatile. The
> purpose of const is to announce objects that may be placed in
> read-only memory, and perhaps to increase opportunities for
> optimization.

In G++ you will receive the error for the second case ie, `const int a;`.

> **6.9.2 External object definitions**
>
> **Semantics**
>
> 1 If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and
> an initializer, the declaration is an external definition for the
> identifier.
>
> 2 A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope
> without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with
> the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a tentative
> definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative
> definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no
> external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly
> as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
> identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation
> unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

declares a constant integer variable. It means it’s value can’t be modified. It’s value is initially assigned to 10.
If you try to change its value later, the compiler will issue a warning, or an error, depending on your compiler settings.