# What is the purpose of const qualifier if I can modify it through a pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, qualifiers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the evil cast get trumped by the evil compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712334/does-the-evil-cast-get-trumped-by-the-evil-compiler)

Hello,

If I can modify a constant through a pointer, then what is the purpose of it?
Below is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 const int a = 10;
 int *p = (int *)&a;

 printf("Before: %d \n", a);
 *p = 2;
 /*a = 2; gives error*/

 printf("After: %d \n", *p);

 return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

> Before: 10
>   After: 2
>   Press any key to continue . . .

Using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: See [Does the evil cast get trumped by the evil compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712334/does-the-evil-cast-get-trumped-by-the-evil-compiler).  This is [undefined behavior](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: Now compile with optimizations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason you could modify the value is because you did a pointer typecast that stripped off the `const`ness:

```
int *p = (int *)&a;
```

This typecasts a `const int*` (namely `&a`) to an `int *`, allowing you to freely modify the variable.  Normally the compiler would warn you about this, but the explicit typecast suppressed the warning.

The main rationale behind `const` at all is to prevent you from accidentally modifying something that you promised not to.  It's not sacrosanct, as you've seen, and you can cast away `const`ness with impunity, much in the same way that you can do other unsafe things like converting pointers to integers or vice-versa.  The idea is that you should try your best not to mess with `const`, and the compiler will warn you if you do.  Of course, adding in a cast tells the compiler "I know what I'm doing," and so in your case the above doesn't generate any sort of warnings.

Answer (score 9):

> If i can modify a constant through a
>   pointer then what is the purpose of
>   it? below is code:

This is Undefined Behavior and should be avoided at all costs:

> § **C99 6.7.3p5**
>
> If an attempt is made to modify an
>   object defined with a const-qualified
>   type through use of an lvalue with
>   non-const-qualified type, **the
>   behavior is undefined**.

Comment: "should be avoided at all costs" But what if a person said they'd hurt me if I didn't? :(

Comment: @GMan Sacrificing one's self to prevent UB guarantees a spot in Coding Nirvana where the `static` keyword has only one meaning and the release date of Perl 6 is known.

Comment: You mean they bother with non-Lisp languages in Coding Nirvana?

Comment: If I was smart enough to write compilers, I'd make one that gave me a new Ferrari every time someone did this.