# Can a non-const pointer modify a const var int c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

Here is my test code:

```
#define print(A) cout << #A <<  " = " << A <<  endl;
int main()
{
    const int e = 2;
    int *p = (int *)&e;
    *p = 4;

    print(e);
    print(*p);
    print(&e);
    print(p);
}
```

Result:

```
e = 2;
*p = 4;
&e = 0xbfc6b458;
p = 0xbfc6b458;
```

Since "p" points to "e" according to their identical address, how can *p and "e" be different??? This can be dangerous, right?

Comment: use `const_cast` instead or use a const int*

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of const qualifier if I can modify it through a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841419/what-is-the-purpose-of-const-qualifier-if-i-can-modify-it-through-a-pointer-in-c)

Comment: If the compiler puts the constant in a read-only page, an attempt to change it would trigger a general protection fault.

Comment: You invoke UB. anythign can happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Casting away `const` is legal; using the pointer (or reference) thus acquired to (attempt to) modify a `const` object is illegal.

Your code results in undefined behaviour; it can do anything and it doesn't have to make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying a constant variable in any way results in an **Undefined Behavior**.
So yes this is dangerous.
An Undefined Behavior means that any behavior is possible and you cannot expect any valid behavior. The compiler is free to give you any results and it is allowed by the Standard to do so. Once an UB is invoked the program is not a valid program anymore.So best is to avoid any code which causes an UB.

Answer (score 1):

They can be different because "e" is a const, so any decent compiler will plug in the value at compile time instead of reading it from memory.

Since you take the address there's still a "real" variable for it, but it's not actually used in your case.

And you're "lucky" that you could modify the value at all; since it was declared "const", the compiler could have placed it into readonly memory.

Either way, modifying a const value yields "undefined behavior". Lucky for us, you didn't destroy the world with your foolish game.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to write to a constant variable (yes, the name is pretty oxymoron but I digress) which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting away const. which is giving you wrong value which is Undefined behaviour.
It should be either

```
int e = 2;
int* p = (int *)&e;
*p = 4;
```

or

```
const int e = 2;
const int* p = (const int *)&e;
*p = 4;
```

latter one will give you compilation error as you are writting to a const.

Answer (score 0):

Define variable:

```
 const int e = 2;
```

directive const tell c/c++ compiler check whether L-value of e variable, compiler will prevent your code assign new value for e.

```
int* p = (int *)&e;
```

p is a pointer (also int 4 bytes), can be assigned any value , p = (((int *) e ) -2)+2. The compiler no need to check *p whether *p is constant. I think that is a flexible of c/c++ languages, the better way is avoiding pointer.