# Change of const variable in c

Tags: c, pointers, constants

```
const int a = 10;
int main()
{
    int *p = &a;
    *p = 100;
    printf ("%d\n", *p);
}
```

The above code crashes, which is as per the expectation.

Now check the below code (Change the variable `a` from global to local variable).

```
int main()
{
    const int a = 10;

    int *p = &a;
    *p = 100;
    printf ("%d\n", *p);
}
```

The code prints 100 as the output.
My question is that why read-write access is allowed for the local const variable?

Comment: It isn't allowed. You are invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: It is [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21372713/1708801), possible duplicate.

Comment: global const may be on a memory segment which is clearly marked "read only" by the OS and protected as such. stack const is not really const at the assembly level.

Comment: And you’re ignoring a warning. A compiler may refuse to compile your code.

Comment: In the question linked above, a [comment notes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372713/confusion-regarding-modification-of-const-variable-using-pointers/21372732#comment32231156_21372732) ... `It's actually fairly hard for implementations to put const objects with automatic storage in read-only memory;`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841419/what-is-the-purpose-of-const-qualifier-if-i-can-modify-it-through-a-pointer-in-c?rq=1