# In C, can a const variable be modified via a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I wrote some thing similar to this in my code

```
const int x=1;
int *ptr;
ptr = &x;
*ptr = 2;
```

Does this work on all compilers?  Why doesn't the GCC compiler notice that we are changing a constant variable?

Comment: It does.  You should get a message like `warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type`, referring to the line `ptr = &x;`.

Comment: This has some info too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945640/constants-and-pointers-in-c?lq=1

Comment: Hypothetically, a compiler could put a `const int` into read-only memory. Then `*ptr = 2;` would crash. De facto, don't expect it to crash. Oh, and the compiler will complain about discarding the qualifier on `ptr = &x;` if you let it.

Comment: My compiler declares an error `ptr = &x;`  incompatible types 'int *' and 'const int *

Comment: I have ran this code on GCC compiler i got a warning and no run time error or compilation error.

Comment: @BillHicks And I once was stabbed with a knife but didn't die... does that prove that stabbings aren't fatal?

Comment: In C, `const type var` says the variable won't be changed _here_, it could be changed _elsewhere_. I.e., you can do `int i; void f(const int); f(i);`. In the above, `var` is still a variable. In C++ it is a bona-fide constant (probably what @Armin is doing).

Comment: Have any of the answers below helped?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`const` actually doesn't mean "constant". Something that's "constant" in C has a value that's determined at compile time; a literal `42` is an example. The `const` keyword really means read-only. Consider, for example:

```
const int r = rand();
```

The value of `r` is not determined until program execution time, but the `const` keyword means that you're not permitted to modify `r` after it's been initialized.

In your code:

```
const int x=1;
int *ptr;
ptr = &x;
*ptr = 2;
```

the assignment `ptr = &x;` is a *constraint violation*, meaning that a conforming compiler is required to complain about it; you can't legally assign a `const int*` (pointer to const int) value to a non-const `int*` object. *If* the compiler generates an executable (which it needn't do; it could just reject it), then the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

For example, the generated code might actually store the value `2` in `x` -- but then a later reference to `x` might yield the value `1`, because the compiler *knows* that `x` can't have been modified after its initialization. And it knows that because you told it so, by defining `x` as `const`. If you lie to the compiler, the consequences can be arbitrarily bad.

Actually, the worst thing that can happen is that the program behaves as you expect it to; that means you have a bug that's very difficult to detect. (But the diagnostic you should have gotten will have been a large clue.)

Comment: Standard reference: C11 6.5.4/3

Comment: [This compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) allows such a statement: `int *ptr = (int*)&x;` but not `int *ptr = &x;`. Additionally, `printf("%d %d",x,*ptr);` outputs the result `1 2` while `printf("%p %p",&x, ptr);` outputs the same address for both `&x` and `ptr` (something like 0x7ffe6a1aa47c). Is that counted as mistake/ bug or does it serve a purpose? Is that behavior language-related or compiler-related?

Comment: @Xfce4 I'd count `int *ptr = (int*)&x;` as a mistake by the programmer. I'd expect most C compilers to accept it without complaint (no diagnostic is required). The cast means that the conversion is not a constraint violation, but it does have undefined behavior. Given `const int x = 1;`, the compiler may legitimately assume that `x` continues to have the value `1`, and need not generate code to read it again. If you go behind the compiler's back to write `2` to that memory location, you've lied to the compiler and it will get its revenge.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I was about to ask how it could be possible that the same address yields two different results for `x` and `*ptr`, but trying `printf("%d %d %d\n",x,*(&x),*ptr);` gave the output `1 2 2`. So it looks like `x` is different than `*(&x)`, which implies -to me- that the values and addresses are stored, linked and/or called in a 'not-straightforward' way.

Comment: @Xfce4 The values and addresses are stored straightforwardly. What's not straightforward is that the compiler knows that `x` was defined with `const`, so it assumes its value cannot change, so it replaces the reference to `x` with the equivalent of a literal `1`. This is a perfectly valid optimization. It gives unexpected results here because the programmer cheated.

Comment: @KeithThompson Oh I was assuming that the values `1 2 2` were decided at runtime. So `x` was replaced by `1` at "compile-time" for optimization? It makes sense now. As a side question, is it possible for the compiler to replace `*(&x)` and `*ptr` in a similar way for optimization or are pointers exempt from that, i.e. the corresponding values to the pointers must be calculated/ obtained at runtime?

Comment: @Xfce4 Pointer objects are in most ways like any other objects. If a pointer object is defined with `const`, the compiler can assume that its value is unchanged. If the program cheats and modifies the object's value, the behavior is undefined. (So don't do that.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I meant if it would be possible for the compiler to determine that a value pointed by the pointer won't be changed, and as a result a statement like `*(&x)` would be replaced by a constant value at "compile-time" rather than runtime.

Comment: @Xfce4 To be clear, pointers point to objects, not to values. If a compiler can determine that the object pointed to by a pointer is defined with `const`, then it can assume the value is unchanged. Given `const int x = 42;`, a compiler can replace `*&x` by a constant `42`. (Whether it actually does so depends on how clever the compiler is.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you. Is it possible for a compiler to do the same when `const` keyword is not used, but the pointed object's value does not change at all?

Comment: @Xfce4 Sure. A compiler can replace `{ int x = 42; printf("%d\n", x); }` by `puts("42")` -- as long as it can prove that the value of `x` is unchanged (given the assumption that the code has defined behavior). An implementation is required to produce the specified behavior. The standard doesn't care how it does so.

Comment: @KeithThompson Can more complicated expressions like `*(&x)` be replaced by the compiler at compile time, provided that they will not change even though `const` keyword is not used. Can compiler detect that? This is the ultimate question I was trying to ask.

Comment: @Xfce4 I thought I answered that. The implementation's obligation is to produce the defined behavior of the program. Any code it generates is just a means to that end. (And if the program has undefined behavior, all bets are off.)

Answer (score 4):

[Online C 2011 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> #### 6.7.3 Type qualiﬁers
>
> ...
> 6 **If an attempt is made to modify an object deﬁned with a const-qualiﬁed type through use
> of an lvalue with non-const-qualiﬁed type, the behavior is undeﬁned**. If an attempt is
> made to refer to an object deﬁned with a volatile-qualiﬁed type through use of an lvalue
> with non-volatile-qualiﬁed type, the behavior is undeﬁned.<sup>133)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>133) This applies to those objects that behave as if they were deﬁned with qualiﬁed types, even if they are
> never actually deﬁned as objects in the program (such as an object at a memory-mapped input/output
> address).</sup>

Emphasis added.

Since the behavior is left undefined, the compiler is not required to issue a diagnostic, nor is it required to halt translation.  This would be difficult to catch in the general case; suppose you had a function like

```
void foo( int *p ) { *p = ...; }
```

defined in it's own separate translation unit.  During translation, the compiler has no way of knowing if `p` could be pointing to a `const`-qualified object or not.  If your call is something like

```
const int x;
foo( &x );
```

you *may* get a warning like `parameter 1 of 'foo' discards qualifiers` or something similarly illuminating.

Also note that the `const` qualifier doesn't necessarily mean that the associated variable will be stored in read-only memory, so it's possible the above code would "work" (update the value in `x`) in that you'd successfully update `x` by doing an end-run around the `const` semantics.  But then you might as well just not declare `x` to be `const`.

Comment: It would be good to also mention that OP's code is a constraint violation, before we get so far as 6.7.3/6.  (the reference is C11 6.5.4/3)

Answer (score -1):

Bad programmer. No Moon Pie!

If you need to modify a const, copy it to a non-const variable and then work with it. It's const for a reason. Trying to "sneak" around a const can cause serious runtime issues. i.e. the optimizer has likely used the value inline, etc.

```
const int x=1;
int non_const_x = x;
non_const_x = 2;
```

Comment: If you need to modify a `const` (not constant) object, don't define it as `const` in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

There is a good discussion of this here:[Does the evil cast get trumped by the evil compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712334/does-the-evil-cast-get-trumped-by-the-evil-compiler)

I would expect gcc to compile this because:

- ptr is allowed to point to x, otherwise reading it would be impossible, although as the comment below says it's not exactly brilliant code and the compiler should complain. Warning options will (I guess) affect whether or not it's actually warned about.
- when you write to x, the compiler no longer "knows" that it is writing to a const, all this is in the coders hands in C. However, it does really know, so it may well warn you, depending on the warning options you've selected.

whether it works or not, however, will depend on how the code is compiled, the way const is implemented for the compile options selected and the target CPU and architecture. It may work. Or it may crash. Or you may write to a "random" bit of memory and cause (or not) some freaky effect. It's not a good coding strategy, but that wasn't your question :-)

Comment: `ptr` **isn't** allowed to point to `x`; the compiler should (and does) complain.  You would need `const int *ptr` for the assignment to be valid.