# Confusion regarding modification of const variable using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, constants

Following example added confusion in my understanding. I'm unable to understand how is it possible to modify the const variable local. Please help me to understand the same.

```
 /* Compile code without optimization option */
 // volatile.c
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(void)
 {
     const int local = 10;
     int *ptr = (int*) &local;

     printf("Initial value of local : %d \n", local);

     *ptr = 100;

     printf("Modified value of local: %d \n", local);

     return 0;
}
```

$ gcc volatile.c -o volatile –save-temps

$ ./volatile

Initial value of local : 10

Modified value of local: 100

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576000/in-c-can-a-const-variable-be-modified-via-a-pointer)

Comment: As for "how it is possible", it's because you're deliberately subverting its `const`ness by changing it through a non-`const` pointer, and your compiler has not elected to put it in read-only memory or do something else that would just cause a spectacular failure.

Comment: So, does that mean the compiler is wrong? It should have should the warning

Comment: No, it means that you're wrong. That being said, if you actually turn your compiler warnings up to a sensible level by adding `-std=c99 -pedantic -Wall` to your command line, my money says that gcc will warn you about this.

Comment: @codeymodey undefined behavior does not require a warning and in many cases may actually appear to work just fine but could break at a later time.

Comment: so that is bad..for a good secure code

Comment: It's nothing to do with security. `const` is there to help the *programmer* - i.e. you - avoid making mistakes by accidentally changing something he/she did not intend to change. You never *have* to make something `const` in the first place, so subverting it is not a security issue - it's just you asking the compiler for some help, and then immediately choosing to ignore the help it gives you.

Comment: if I have username and password to connect to a database, to keep it read only I declare it const. Now, if it possible to change the value, so isn't that a hole?

Comment: No, because it's also possible - and easier - to change the value by just not declaring it `const` in the first place. It's your program, nobody else is going to be able to change those values unless you give them a way to do so, or unless they modify the executable, which you can't do anything about. The real security hole is keeping a username and password inside your program to begin with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simply [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if we look at the C99 draft standard section `6.7.3` *Type qualifiers* paragraph *4* it says:

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use
>   of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. If an attempt is
>   made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue
>   with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.<sup>115)</sup>

So you can not have any expectations on the results and you should not be doing this.

If we look at paragraph *2* it says:

> The properties associated with qualified types are meaningful only for expressions that
>   are lvalues.<sup>114)</sup>

and footnote `114` says:

> The implementation may place a const object that is not volatile in a read-only region of
>   storage. Moreover, the implementation need not allocate storage for such an object if its address is never used.

In general the implementation does not have to make *const* variables *read-only* but it may but as R.. points out placing an automatic variable in read-only memory would be hard.

Comment: +1 for may make const variables read-only.  Happens all the time in embedded application.

Comment: So, above result just happened. But actually it might or might not happen. Also, I didn't get the last part "The implementation may place a const object that is not volatile in a read-only region of storage. Moreover, the implementation need not allocate storage for such an object if its address is never used."

Comment: @codeymodey in `gcc` I can get similar results but in `clang` I can repeat your results, which is typical of undefined behavior. Using an [online compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator) can help you experiment with different ones.

Comment: @codeymodey well volatile variables can not be in read-only memory since they can be modified from outside sources but otherwise the compiler has the option of placing `const` objects in read only memory but does not have to.

Comment: I meant to say in `clang` I `can not` repeat the results.

Comment: It's actually fairly hard for implementations to put const objects *with automatic storage* in read-only memory; doing so would require a stack with portions that change between writable and read-only at each point where a new const-qualified object's lifetime begins.